# Convert jQuery Colorbox to act as a user dialog?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

**Is there a nice and easy way to have a Colorbox act as a dialog window?** I understand there are enough events which can be addressed but I'm unable to construct this in a nifty way... Or are there existing ways to **replace** the `close` button with `ok/cancel` or `yes/no` or other buttons..?

Edit:
I need to be able to pass somesort of return function (similar to an event) and execute that based on a button click in the dialog (box). Functionality similar to [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) "buttons"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/convert-jquery-colorbox-to-act-as-a-user-dialog

**JS**

```
    $(function() {
        $(".example").colorbox({
            onOpen : function() {
                $('#cboxClose').html('<div id="cboxClose"><a class="btn" href="#yes">yes</a><a class="btn" href="#no">no</a></div>').children().unwrap('<div>');
            }
        });

        $(document).on("click", "a.btn", function(e) {
            if (this.hash == '#yes')
                alert('yes');
            else
                alert('no');

            return false;
        });
    });
```

**CSS** colorbox reset

```
#cboxClose {
    background: transparent;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

**UPDATED** ( to work with latest **jQuery 1.9.1** and **colorbox 1.4.4**  )

Comment: I mean something like the jQuery UI Dialog 'Buttons' functionality... http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-buttons

Comment: ah very clean solution! Thanks!

Comment: Note that this solution is broken since colorbox 1.4 due to the close tag now being a Button tag instead of a div.

Comment: Reported here (the author will fix it, in the meantime 1.3.34 is ok): https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/350

Comment: @Nicolas Cadilhac: fixed! see the new demo.